# Oauth2 Spring Security Authorization Code

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to reproduce the oauth server provided here:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v
The curl call for testing this basic server should be:

```
curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token  \
-d grant_type=authorization_code -d client_id=acme     \
-d redirect_uri=http://example.com -d code=jYWioI
```

Though I keep getting the following error:
    Invalid authorization code: jYWioI

Where is this authorization code to be configured in the authorization server?

Comment: Where is that source code? I can't find it on that site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate a new authorization code!

You can do it using the grant type authorization_code or password

**Using the authorization_code:**

Open your browser and to visit the authorization endpoint 
http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://example.com

After the login process (login: user password: password), you will be redirected to 
http://example.com/?code=CODE <-- this is the code that you should use in the next request

now you get the token:

```
curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token -d grant_type=authorization_code -d client_id=acme -d redirect_uri=http://example.com -d code=CODE
```

response: {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJS....."}

**Using the password grantType:**

```
curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token  -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password
```

response: {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJS....."}

I recommend you to read more about oauth grantTypes, to know what's is better for your solution
https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Comment: is the login page provided by spring itself?

Comment: yes, there is a default login view provided by spring which you can override @user962206

Comment: Spring provided login is session based. How to make it token(JWT) based?