# Spring OAuth2 google login + username & password login

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm creating a Spring Boot REST API for a website/app, and want to give the users the ability to login using either username & password or using google.

**Username + password login**

- POST /oauth/token + basic auth with APP client_id:client_secret

  - grant_type = password
  - username = app username
  - password = app password
  - client_id = app client id (not google client)

After this post request, the frontend (React app) should get a JWT for accessing resources on resource server. (google is not involved)

**Google login**

- Obtain authorization_code from google using google login and google client_id
- POST /oauth/token + basic auth with APP client_id:client_secret

  - grant_type = authorization_code
  - client_id = app client id (not google)
  - code = {authorization code from google login}
- Server exchanges google authorization_code for access token and retrieves user info.
- The server creates/updates app user using google user info

User is presented with a google login screen which will return an authorization code that can later be exchanged for a google access token. The authorization code is the sent to server using the /oauth/token endpoint, so server can exchange the code for a token in order to get the users info.

So far i have the username/password flow working using OAuth2 password flow and this configuration in authorization server config:

```
  @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("testclient")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(""))
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .authorities("create_users")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1200)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50000);
    }
```

I have added the "authorization_code" grant type to the client, but can't figure out how to authenticate using that grant type with postman.
I have tried calling google api to get the authorization code and then calling my API with:

/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code={google_auth_code}

But i just get an error: Invalid authorization code

I was hoping that Spring would call google api using the authorization code and fetch the user info.

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oauth2 Spring Security Authorization Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377971/oauth2-spring-security-authorization-code)

Comment: @mentallurg not quite. My issue is, that I'm trying to authorize facebook/google through my own api. So the authorization code is being obtained in the front end, and then sent to backend api which should then forward it to facebook/google server in order to get the users info. I'm not sure that my understanding of this flow is correct.

Comment: *the authorization code is being obtained in the front end* - do you mean that user enters this code? Otherwise please describe in more detail your technical design - what components / systems you have, what are their roles.

Comment: @mentallurg I have tried to clarify my question.